python, Flask, хостинг reg.ru, не работает render_template
Во flask на хостинге reg.ru не работает функция render_template. Не загружает шаблон main.html который находится в той же директории что и hello.py запускаемый файл. Не могу найти даже ошибку, из за которой не работает render_template. В чем может быть проблема?
При выполнении кода
from flask import Flask, render_template


application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   application.run(host='0.0.0.0')

 (без render_template, просто возвращаю html код), все работает корректно.
Директория:

Все выполнял по гайду https://help.reg.ru/support/hosting/php-asp-net-i-skripty/kak-ustanovit-flask-na-hosting
код с render_template
from flask import Flask, render_template


application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template(main.html)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   application.run(host='0.0.0.0')


вызывает ошибку
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete                 
your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in 
the application.


Лог ошибки:
File "/var/www/u2586830/data/www/internet-history.ru/hello.py", line 9, in hello


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Исправил, добавил лог

Исправленый код:
from flask import Flask, render_template


application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')

Ошибка заключалась в том, что вы не заключили return render_template(main.html) main.html в кавычки. После исправления все заработало.
